# Arrays in Javascripts

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that is defined like so: `var alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c'];`. How do I print the array which results in something like this?

```
a
b
c
```

I have my own code but it doesn't solve my problem because it prints the value of an array like this:

```
a,b,c
```

Comment: Do you just want to print each element?  `alpha.forEach(function(x) { console.log(x); })`

Comment: Print it like that where?  In HTML?  Or the console?  What for?

Comment: Do you want this output to appear on the console? Can you `join` the elements of the array with a `"\n"` "separator"?

Comment: Looks like you need to learn about [loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Answer (score 9):

Just use the length of the array to iterate it with a `for` loop:

```
var alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for (var i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
  console.log(alpha[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Join the elements together with a carriage return:

```
var alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var oneString = alpha.join('\n');
alert(oneString);
```

Or you could use `console.log(oneString)`. You don't even need the intermediate variable - you could do

```
var alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
console.log(alpha.join('\n'));
```

Nice and compact. The `join()` function will concatenate the elements of the array; it will normally use the comma as separator, but you can override this with your own separator (the argument to the function). That's how this works - very compact, no iterating.

see http://jsfiddle.net/znAPK/

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript Array global object is a constructor for arrays, which are high-level, list-like objects.

Syntax

```
[element0, element1, ..., elementN]
new Array(element0, element1, ..., elementN)
new Array(arrayLength)

var arr = ["this is the first element", "this is the second element"];
console.log(arr[0]);              // prints "this is the first element"
console.log(arr[1]);              // prints "this is the second element"
console.log(arr[arr.length - 1]); // prints "this is the second element"
```

Try this syntax according to your code